# Why is the request body of my Cypress Post request empty?

Tags: node.js, cypress

I am writing a Cypress test for my Node backend API. The test sends a POST request with some headers and body, which includes some required parameters for the backend to work with.

The strange thing is that the endpoint is just receiving an empty `request.body`.

This is how my Cypress test looks like, you can see how I send the request body:

```js
    it('onboards a repo - POST', () => {
        cy.request({
            method: 'POST',
            url: `/my/${org}/endpoint`,
            headers: headers,
            body: {
                productId: productId,
                requestorEmail: requestorEmail
            }
        }).then( (response) => {
            expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
        });
    });
```

**Edit**: These are the headers I'm sending:

```js
    const headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json, text/plain',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer <MY_TOKEN>',
    };
```

Any idea why I am not receiving anything inside the `request.body` in the backend?

Comment: @szogoon it is an API whic is consumed by other services, no frontend involved. But I have run it with Postman and it works fine. Also, when runing the Cypress tests, it says: `The request we sent was: ...` and there I can see the expected request body content.

Comment: @szogoon thanks for clarifying that point. I have run `npx cypress open` and then run the test there but I can't find the call in the Network tab of the browser's developer tools. I do see this message from Cypress: `The request we sent was: ... Body: {"productId":"10519", "requestorEmail":"cypress_e2e_test@foo.com"}` which is what I expect.

Comment: @szogoon `cy.request()` does not send XHR from the browser, these requests are sent from Cypress's nodejs process, so they do not display in DevTools https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request#Request-is-not-displayed-in-the-Network-Tab-of-Developer-Tools

Comment: Where are you setting `productId` and `requestorEmail`?

Comment: @DJSDev is right, I'll delete my bad suggestions

Comment: It is possible that the headers you are sending with the POST request are incorrect, or that the body is not being encoded in the correct format. Try sending the request with Postman or cURL and see what headers and body they send. You may also need to add a `Content-Type` header with the request.

Comment: @ebanster I just edited my question adding the headers I'm sending, with the content type. I think they are pretty standard as well.

Comment: @agoff I'm setting those variables just above the snippet I pasted. I have checked that they are set and their values are read correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw your discussion on Cypress's Github, but you seem to be active on here, so I'll crosspost.

Your issue is the Content-Type header. Cypress doesn't like `'application/json, text/plain'`, but changing it to `'application/json'` should fix it.